# Ubuntu Server 13.10 With Clonezilla SE

Tags: ubuntu, clone, clonezilla

[image]I have installed Clonezilla SE on my system. When I run "sudo clonezilla start" the program begins, however, it seems to be the Clonezilla live version and not the SE version. I have installed drbl and I know I installed the proper version. When I run the progam the programs title only says Clonezilla, DRBL like I have seen in several tutorials. Can anyone tell me if there is a differance in the screens or if both programs are downloaded when I installed drbl and I am simply running the wrong version of Clonezilla? Also I have tried running /opt/drbl/sbin/dcs as I saw in a tutorial, it came back with "command not found", I also tried "/opt/drbl/sbin/drblsrv -i" with the same result. I am still new at linux so if I am missing a set in setup or just forgot anything please let me know. 
Thank you in advance for your help. I am not above exploring any option.

P.S. The image attached is one of the screens I am getting. Please let me know if you can tell if I am running the proper version.
P.P.S I am taking any ideas!

Comment: Any ideas you can give me I will explore!

Comment: It looks like normal Clonezilla to me... have you tried just using it?  If it does what you want, how much do you care whether it's "the right version"?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you try "sudo drblsrv -i" instead of the full path? After you configure (drblsrv -i) then "sudo drblpush -i" to set the network interfaces and finally you can run "sudo dcs"